How do I modify the sequence of numbers in parentheses on the left side of a Jupyter Notebook cell?
Jupyter shows a cell number to the left of each cell:

I wonder why the left braced sequence of numbers in the Jupyter Notebook cell only shows odd numbers.
When I change a file, it may appear as an even number, so how do I set up the sequence of numbers to their original state?

"so how do i set up the sequence of numbers to their original state." Normally, you do that by selecting under 'Kernel', 'Restart and Run All Cells'. However... there was an issue with a version of an extension recently where it was messing up numbering of cells in Jupyter, see this post 'Cell numbering broken on new Jupyter lab/notebook' here athe Jupyter Discourse forum. Is that maybe what you are trying to describe? The issue seemed to be an extension Anaconda was including.

“However... there was an issue with a version of an extension recently where it was messing up numbering of cells in Jupyte”，Thanks. I figured it was jupyter

No, I wasn't saying it was Jupyter. It was an extension added by Anaconda in the case I referenced. They are not the same. Plus, you didn't really clarify what was happening specifically to you? Not adequately addressing that makes your post less helpful to others when it could indeed maybe be helpful to others and is how SO is meant to work. Was that your cause, too?

Sorry I didn't describe it clearly and correctly, it was indeed caused by anaconda and the issue was fixed when I updated anaconda and jupyyer.

Please update the end of your post with that information clearly linking to the related material. Or post an answer with this information.

It was an issue with a version of an extension recently where it was messing up numbering of cells in Jupyter, see this post 'Cell numbering broken on new Jupyter lab/notebook' here athe Jupyter Discourse forum.
The issue was fixed when I updated anaconda and jupyyer.
Thanks Wayne for your help!
